# How to tell QuickCheck to generate only valid list indices for a parameter?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

Say I want to write some unit tests for the `(!!)` function.

```
my_prop xs n = ...
```

I want to restrict n to only valid indexes and I know I could do something like

```
my_prop xs n = (not.null) (drop n xs) ==> ...
```

But this makes it so that the vast majority of the generated cases are invalid and get thrown away. Is there a way I can set things up so that QuickCheck generates the `xs` list first and uses its value to generate only valid cases of `n`?

Comment: Make a new type that contains a list and an `Int` with an appropriate `Arbitrary` instance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using [`forAll`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/latest/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:forAll), you can specify a [generator](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/latest/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html) for `n` which depends on the earlier arguments, e.g.

```
my_prop (NonEmpty xs) = forAll (choose (0, length xs - 1)) $ \n -> ...
```

Comment: Neat. If I need two indices in the propety, how can I pass a Gen (Int,Int) to forAll? My current solution is nesting forAll like so: `forAll (indices xs) $ \x -> forAll (indices xs) $ \y -> ...` (using Daniel Fischer's indices definition seen in another answer).

Answer (score 10):

You can make a generator that only creates valid indices and write your property like

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Gen
import System.Random

indices :: [a] -> Gen Int
indices xs = MkGen $ \sg _ -> fst $ randomR (0, length xs - 1) sg

my_prop :: [Char] -> Property
my_prop xs = not (null xs) ==> forAll (indices xs) (\i -> xs !! i /= '0')
```

eliminating the `Int` argument.

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by Daniel Wagner, one possibility is creating my own datatype and giving it an `Arbitrary` instance.

```
data ListAndIndex a = ListAndIndex [a] Int deriving (Show)

instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (ListAndIndex a) where
   arbitrary = do
     (NonEmpty xs) <- arbitrary
     n  <- elements [0..(length xs - 1)]
     return $ ListAndIndex xs n
```

`NonEmpty` is from a custom type in `Test.QuickCheck.Modifiers` for generating non empty lists.