# Property Based Testing with Exceptions

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, testing, quickcheck, smallcheck

I am writing an introduction to Haskell for my local functional programming group.
As a base I am using the Tasty-testing framework and I want to test the indexing function `(!!)`.

`MinimalExample.hs`

```
module MinimalExample where

myIndex :: Int -> [a] -> a                                               
myIndex _ [] = error "index too large"                                   
myIndex 0 (x:_) = x                                                      
myIndex n (_:xs) = myIndex (n-1) xs
```

`MinimalTests.hs`

```
module MinimalTests where

import Test.Tasty
import Test.Tasty.SmallCheck as SC
import Test.SmallCheck.Series

import MinimalExample

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain tests

tests :: TestTree
tests = testGroup "Tests" [scProps]

scProps ::  TestTree
scProps = testGroup "(checked by SmallCheck)"
  [ SC.testProperty "(!!) == myIndex" $ \lst n ->
      lst !! n == myIndex (n::Int) (lst::[Int])
  ]
```

The tests should *not* fail on "too large indices" as the Errors/Exceptions are the same.

The tests should fail with negative input - which could be resolved by adding `NonNegative` as a constraint on the input, or adding the respective clause in the `myIndex`-function.

- Can I test for exceptions in property based tests?
- Or do I have to use (H)Unit-tests like in [How do I test for an error in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350164/how-do-i-test-for-an-error-in-haskell) or [Haskell exceptions and unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802640/haskell-exceptions-and-unit-testing) , in this case how do I choose the Index in the range of 0 to length of the generated testing list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell QuickCheck to generate only valid list indices for a parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827861/how-to-tell-quickcheck-to-generate-only-valid-list-indices-for-a-parameter)

Comment: thanks for the link, but the answers to it do not solve the problem of testing for the exceptions

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [spoon](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/spoon-0.3.1/docs/Control-Spoon.html) package, or write a similar function that would return the exception if you want to test that the exceptions are the same.